# Permission for edit articles and users

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, acl

It's possible, on Joomla 3.2, create a group with permission for:

- insert/edit/delete articles
- insert/edit/delete users

and not permissions for manage extensions, configuration, templates..?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can add your own group or use one of the existing ones and set permissions accordingly. See [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial#Global_Configuration). Each core component has an ACL Manager so you need to change it for the Article Manager and Extension Manager

Comment: but whatever the case, upgrade your Joomla to 3.4.1

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

1. Go to Users -> Groups
2. Click New button and create a custom group
3. Go to Content -> Article Manager
4. Click on Options button on toolbar
5. Click on Permissions tab
6. Click on your custom user group (left side tabs) to show its permissions
7. Select Allowed for Create, Edit Own and Edit State (or Delete if you want to  give more permission)
8. Click Save & Close